# Definite integral related to even function property

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $\displaystyle f\left( x \right)=\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ g\left( t
>  \right) dt }$,where g is an even function and $f(x+5)=g(x)$ then how
>   to prove the following $$g(0)-g(x)=\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ f\left( t \right) dt }$$

Comment: I just deduced that f(x)+f(-x) is 0 which implies f(x) is odd.After that?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $g$ is even and $f$ odd.
Then for all $x$:

$$f(x+5)=g(x)=g(-x)=f(-x+5)=-f(x-5)$$
Hence we get 
$$f(x+10)+f(x)=0$$
This is
$$g(x+5)+f(x)=0$$
As $f^{\prime}(x)=g(x)$ (from the first relation) we have
$$f^{\prime}(x+5)+f(x)=0$$

But as $g(x)=f(x+5)$ this is
$$g^{\prime}(x)+f(x)=0$$
And now it is easy to finish.